# R: Plots of subset still include excluded attributes, how do I get draw a plot without them?

Tags: r, plot, ggplot2, boxplot

I am trying to draw a boxplot in R:

I have a dataset with 70 attributes:
The format is

```
  patient number       medical_speciality      number_of_procedures
   111                    Ortho                      21
   232                    Emergency                  16
   878                    Pediatrics                 20
   981                    OBGYN                      31
   232                    Care of Elderly            15
   211                    Ortho                      32
   238                    Care of Elderly            11
   219                    Care of Elderly            6
   189                    Emergency                  67
   323                    Emergency                  23
   189                    Pediatrics                 1
   289                    Ortho                      34
```

I have been trying to get a subset to only include emergency, pediatrics in a boxplot (there are 10000+ datapoints in reality)

I thought that I could just do this:

```
newdata<-subset(olddata[ms$medical_specialty=='emergency'|olddata$medical_specialty=='pediatrics',])
plot(newdata)
```

Since if I do a summary of newdata, all it has is the pediatrics and emergency results. But when it comes to plotting it still includes the ortho, OBGYN, care of elderly in the x axis with no boxplot.

I presume that there is a way to do this in ggplot by doing

```
ggplot(newdata, aes(x=medical_speciality, y=num_of_procedures, fill=cond)) + geom_boxplot()
```

but this gives me the error:
Don't know how to automatically pick scale for object of type data.frame.

Defaulting to continuous
Error: Aesthetics must either be length one, or the same length as the dataProblems:cond

Can someone help me out?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe your problem comes from the fact that the column `medical_speciality` is a factor.

So, even though you subset your data the right way, you still get all the levels (including "Ortho", "OBGYN", etc...).

You can get rid of them by using the function `droplevels`:

```
newdata<-subset(olddata[ms$medical_specialty=='emergency'|olddata$medical_specialty=='pediatrics',])

newdata <- droplevels(newdata) ## THIS IS THE NEW ADDITION

plot(newdata)
```

Does this help?

Comment: Glad it helped :) Could you please accept the answer, so that future persons coming here will see that it works?